# remove_action() not working in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

i'm trying to change the order of my product page in woocommerce but i have a few problems with the remove_action().
I activated the child theme and in my functions.php i'm tryin to remove the add-to-cart button to add it back on another position.

I tried to put my remove_action() into a function that gets executed right after my parent theme loads.

```
function change_order() {
   add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 15 );
   remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'change_order' );
```

The add_action gets excuted but the remove_action() isn't working...
I tried the same with 'init' instead of 'after_setup_theme' but it is still not working...

Does anybody know a solution for my problem ?

Comment: The code seems ok. Just in case, i have tested in my localhost, it worked ok.

Comment: Ok Great. But where is the problem if it isn`t in the code ?

Comment: Try with another theme and check if it works. If yes, then it is because of the theme's woocommerce templates file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different [single product hook](https://wpsites.net/best-plugins/woocommerce-single-product-hooks/)

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','change_order' );
function change_order() {
   add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 15 );
   remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

}
```

Works and tested.